# .NET cannot see installed SDK

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've been working on a C# script recently, and out of the blue I get this error every time I try to run a `dotnet` command:

```
zaphod@eddie:~$ dotnet list-sdks
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.302/dotnet.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '7.0.5' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/

No frameworks were found.

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=7.0.5&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.22.04-x64
```

According to the error message, `dotnet` is installed. I also have noticed that It is trying to access the wrong version of `dotnet` but I need advice on how to fix this.
It's looking for `dotnet` here:
`App: /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.302/dotnet.dll`

But it is searching for 7.0.5.
`Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '7.0.5' (x64)`
I'm running ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I tried purging all the files related to .NET and reinstalling, but now it's throwing this error:

```
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application 'list-sdks' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

I'm not sure, but I doubt it is an issue with the PATH variable as it seems to be running the `dotnet` command, because if it wasn't it would be giving me a "usage:" error.

**Update:**
I tried adding `/usr/bin`, `/usr/share/dotnet`, and `/usr/share/dotnet/sdks` to my PATH variable, but nothing changed.

Comment: You need *two* installs.  The SDK, 7.0.302, you have.  The runtime, 7.0.5, you do not.  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the SDK come with the runtime installed as it says on the official website? I don't know if it is different in Linux as I mostly program on my windows partition.